# ¿Cómo cambiar el color del texto en un recycleview?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview

estoy practicando los toDo list y tengo un layout con fondo negro, así que quisiera poner el texto de mi recyclerView en blanco para que se visualizara todo pero no consigo hacerlo... ¿algún tip?

El código xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="633dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="97dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

y este es el código de mi toDo

```
class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var dbHandler: AdminSQLiteOpenHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
        dbHandler = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this)
        rv_dashboard.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        fab_dashboard.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_dashboard, null)
            val toDoName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ev_todo)
            dialog.setView(view)
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Add") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                if (toDoName.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val toDo = ToDo()
                    toDo.name = toDoName.text.toString()
                    dbHandler.addToDo(toDo)
                    refreshList()
                }
            }
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->

            }
            dialog.show()
        }

    }


    override fun onResume() {
        refreshList()
        super.onResume()
    }

    private fun refreshList(){
        rv_dashboard.adapter = DashboardAdapter(this,dbHandler.getToDos())
    }


    class DashboardAdapter(val context: Context, val list: MutableList<ToDo>):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_dashboard, p0, false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            holder.toDoName.text = list[p1].name
        }

        class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
            val toDoName: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.ev_todo)
        }
    }
}
```

Imagino que para hacerlo tenga que ser desde alguna función que llame al recyclerview ya que en Android Studio no veo ningún atributo que cambie el texto.
También, ¿sería posible hacer que el color de fondo de los campos cambiara cada dos filas? Es decir, primera fila con fondo negro, segunda fila con fondo gris, tercera fila con fondo negro, etc...
Es la primera vez que uso el RecyclerView y ando perdido sobre como funciona.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> quisiera poner el texto de mi recyclerView en blanco

Los recyclerViews no tienen texto, simplemente son contenedores. Lo que debes querer modificar es el color sus elementos. Eso lo puedes hacer agregando el atributo `textColor` a los elementos que tengas en el archivo `rv_child_dashboard.xml`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ev_todo"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    ...
```

> ¿sería posible hacer que el color de fondo de los campos cambiara cada dos filas?

Sí, puedes cambiar el color dependiendo de si la posición es par o impar

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    val color = if (p1 % 2 == 0) R.color.black else R.color.gray
    holder.toDoName.setBackgroundResource(color)
    holder.toDoName.text = list[p1].name
}
```

> Es la primera vez que uso el RecyclerView y ando perdido sobre como funciona.

A esta altura ya no te recomiendo aprenderlo. Hay una [nueva librería](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) para hacer UI con puro Kotlin, los archivos xml, adapters y viewHolders ya no son necesarios. Casualmente hay un
[codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state) que te enseña paso a paso como hacer un TODO list.